# How to create textbox in Modal made using Context in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

It seems events like OnChange dont work in Contexts? It executes but the characters dont link together.

Im trying to make a Modal via context. It pops up but the Text change doesn't respond.

```
     const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
      let { handleModal } = useContext(ModalContext);
    
      const toggleUpdateUsernamePopup = () => {
        handleModal({content: <div>
          <TextBox placeholder={t('unplaceholder')} value={username} onChange={handleModalTextChange} autoFocus type='text' />
          <SubmitButton onClick={submit} text={t('Update', { ns: 'common' })} />
        </div>,description:t('usrupddes'),title:t('usrupd')})
      };
    
      const handleModalTextChange = e => {
        console.log(`e`, e.target.valuee)
        setUsername(e.target.value);
      };
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
  return (
      <ActionButtonContainer btnText={t('usrupd')} onClick={toggleUpdateUsernamePopup} />
  );
```

Comment: Some more context would go a long way. "It executes but the characters don't link together." Can you clarify what this means? Also, is this a custom modal hook of yours or a 3rd party library?

Comment: Please add more details. The code snippet isn't sufficient. For example, there is no `confirmUsername` function definition.

Comment: @BrendanBond Im trying to make a controlled component/text box in a modal. Normally this works but when I move the modal to a hook with the help of Context, Provider, and Portal, the results are weird. I assume it's because the way to modal is made, is the problem. I think maybe it rerenders the entire page and also rewrites the Modal as empty each time. *Its custom

Comment: @SerhiiHolinei the confirm isnt important

Here's the full code related to this issue:
Modal: https://pastebin.com/ZCneWC1A
Context: https://pastebin.com/rjwGBELH
Page: https://pastebin.com/9PJ1rPrq

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, please share more details about your code.
it's not that clear from your snippet

In your answer you might want to include your context file, the origin of all the functions you use, what does modal is expecting to receive, and so on.

usually, when you are working with modals, you need to have a component (for example MyModal) which you are exporting.

then in your upper level (for example "App.js") you might want to add a state:

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
```

then you can share those variables in your context.

in your App.js, you might want to use conditional rendering.

```
{isModalOpen && <MyModal />
```

this way, whenever your "isModalOpen" is equal to true, the modal will be visible.
then you can send more functions to "MyModal" and change other states in your application.

you will have to "inject" the variables to your contexts and grab it in your "MyModal" with useContext.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it isn't possible. State wont pass to context for now.